# If keytool command was successful, do we need to do jarsigner as well?

Tags: keytool

I created a Cordova app called myApp with CLI, then immediately ran this:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore myApp.keystore -alias myApp -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

I put the keystore and apk files in the same folder. When I attempted to sign it with jarsigner with:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore myApp.keystore myApp.apk myApp
```

... I got the output:

```
jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size (expected 814 but got 818 bytes)
```

When I do:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs myApp.apk
```

...the output ended with:

```
jar verified.
```

This means the apk has already been signed. During the process, a "2,048 bit RSA key pair and self-signed certificate (SHA1withRSA) with a validity of 10,000 days" is created. **Does that mean the present myApp.apk does not need a separate jarsigner process applied, and it is ready for Play store as is (assuming it meets all Google Play rules)?**

I've been confused about the jarsigner portion of this whole process, and come to a crashing stop each time I use it. (By "jarsigner portion" I mean implementing *jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore myApp.keystore myApp.apk myApp* after the keytool code.)

**My development environment:**

- Mac OS X 10.9.5 on latest Mac Mini
- Cordova CLI 3.6.3 (cordova, not phonegap)
- Not for PG Build; no Jquery or other JS or CSS packages used
- I am not using Eclipse; I am deliberately learning how to build a signed apk without it.

**Problem stems from the fact that there is a bug in the 3.6.3 version in that release code hasn't been thoroughly documented and implemented.** Filed a bug report on Jira.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are following these [instructions](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually). When building your apk did you compile in [release mode](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html#ReleaseMode) so that it will generate an unsigned apk? Seeing as how you are unable to sign using jarsigner, but verify that it is signed already, I feel the problem may lie with your apk.

Comment: I see the problem then. I used 'cordova build android' instead of 'cordova build android --release' to build the apk, then applied the script to the wrong file. The correct file is HelloCordova-release-unsigned.apk. Once I used these steps, the jarsigner worked successfully.

Comment: If I may ask a followup question, how would I sign a v2 app, in which I would use the v1 key? How would the script differ in that case?